# Scala: Intellij reports false import errors

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, import

Im using intellij community edition, with the JDK 17 (with sources installed if it matters), im getting these strange errors where intellij reports import errors but the compiler doesnt,

i tried using bloop and noticed that it made no difference whether i tried to use gradle or bloop as the build server, vscode and bloop wont report these errors.

i assume its a issue related to intellij,

also i noticed that these errors manifest only using scala 3 the project compiles fine without the import errors.

[image: screenshot of the errors]

i tried using different scala 3 versions, but none solved the problem, but only switching to scala 2 solved the problem
i also tried clearing the Intellij IDE caches and repairing the IDE, none of that worked

Comment: It seems an intellij bug. You can [report the bug at jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-help.html#report-bug)

Comment: Scala 3 support in IntelliJ improves regularly. Are you on latest version of IntelliJ and the scala plugin?